# Why is there no hex file generated when I "build binary output" from the Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-ide

I want to obtain the `.hex` file from my Arduino sketch. I have followed various guides but there is no `.hex` file in my output folder.

How can I obtain my hex file?

Here are my preferences:

> [image: Arduino IDE preferences]

This is the contents of my output folder

> [image: Output folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your setting with the URL for esp8266 package and bin file name with "...generic" I assume you want it for esp8266.

esp8266 doesn't use hex format and "Export compiled binary" creates bin. You can upload it with esptool.

For AVR boards "Export compiled binary" generates hex. You can upload it with avrdude.

Comment: Ah, good catch :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Current versions of Arduino IDE

Use the menu option in the Arduino IDE:

**Sketch** ► **Export Compiled Binary**

See [post #6](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=131655.msg2445740#msg2445740) from the thread [How to get hex file from arduino files ?](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=131655.0):

> Well, since it was bumped it's worth mentioning there is a new way to
>   do this added in Arduino IDE 1.6.5:
>
> - Sketch > Export Compiled Binary
> - If you are doing this with an example then you will be prompted to save the sketch in another location.
> - Wait until the sketch has finished compiling.
> - Sketch > Show Sketch Folder
> - The .hex file will be in the sketch folder

Here is a screenshot for OS X:

> [image: Export compiled Binary menu option]

There is no need to fully compile, a simple verify will suffice. From [post #10](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=131655.msg3118445#msg3118445):

> Reopen Arduino, and open a sketch of your choice (use the Examples->Digital->Blink if you have no other sketches). Hit the Verify button to compile the sketch. Now, navigate to the build.path folder. You should see a bunch of files including one with a .hex extension.

---

### Older versions of Arduino IDE

If using an older version of the Arduino IDE, from [post #12](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=131655.msg3399334#msg3399334):

> Try this if using an older version of Arduino
>
> [Taking out HEX file from Arduino in 3 simple steps](http://arduinoisfun.blogspot.in/2016/01/taking-out-hex-file-from-arduino.html)

1. Open Arduino IDE
2. **File** ► **Preferences** menu

> [image: Arduino IDE Preferences menu]
>
> [image: Arduino IDE Preferences dialog]

3. Find "Show verbose output during " and check the "compilation" box
4. Locate the `preferences.txt` file and open it
5. Add the following line (this is the path to the directory where the hexfile will be stored):

   ```
   build.path=C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\hexfile
   ```
6. Change the following line

   ```
   export.delete_target_folder=true
   ```

   to

   ```
   export.delete_target_folder=false
   ```
7. Quit the Arduino IDE and restart it.
8. Now when you compile, the directory specified in `build.path` will contain the `.hex` file (along with other files which can be ignored)

Comment: did you read my answer?

Comment: Yeah, I had upvoted it... but I missed the ESP bit! I need to pay more attention :-)

Comment: Hi Greenonline, thanks for your thorough answer. Indeed it was the detail about ESP8266 spotted by Juraj that was the key to my issue, but i really appreciate your effort :)